# Can Bootstrap Carousel fit the Screen on mobile or can it be mobile friendly?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.2 Carousel on ReactJS and new to react, I am not sure why is this happening or is this normal, I want the image to fit the screen on mobile is there any other way to fill the gap in the image below?. My Slider.css is empty btw. Thanks

[image]

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import help from '../images/help3.jpeg';
import "../styles/slider.css"

function Slider() {
    return (
        <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src={help} class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src={help} class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src={help} class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
    );
}

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use utilities to set the width and height relative to the viewport. In your case use `min-vh-100` .

**just change  :**

```
<img src={help} class="d-block w-100 " alt="..." />
```

**to :**

```
<img src={help} class="d-block min-vh-100 " alt="..." />
```

Comment: I did what you recommend and fin out that it was half picture in web and whole on mobile the `<img src={help} class="d-block min-vh-100 w=100" alt="..." />`  I just add w-100 and voila and came back to normal on web, thank you so much.